# Prevent insert of same values in MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

Let say that I have table TableA(ColumnCode, ColumnA2, ColumnA3, ColumnA4, ColumnA5).

**Note: ColumnCode(PrimaryKey)is not autoincrement.** What I want to prevent is following scenario:

```
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES(1111, 'val1a', 'val2a', 'val3a', 'val4a', 'val5a')
```

Next insert is with the same values but different ColumnCode:

```
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES(1234, 'val1a', 'val2a', 'val3a', 'val4a', 'val5a')
```

The thing is that I want to prevent inserts like this, where I might have these situations of inserting same values just for another ColumnCode.

Any idea?

**Note2: Next insert is not a problem because I'm not inserting ALL the same column values!!!**

```
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES(1456, 'val1a', 'val2a', 'val3a', 'val32a', 'val654a')
```

As shown, set(ColumnA2, ColumnA3, ColumnA4, ColumnA5) of values is not a duplicate. ColumnA4 and ColumnA5 values are different. So, for me, a duplicate is only when all four of ColumnA values are in table under any ColumnCode.

Hope I cleared my question a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at using [SQL UNIQUE Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

> The UNIQUE constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database
>   table.
>
> The UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints both provide a guarantee for
>   uniqueness for a column or set of columns.
>
> A PRIMARY KEY constraint automatically has a UNIQUE constraint defined
>   on it.
>
> Note that you can have many UNIQUE constraints per table, but only one
>   PRIMARY KEY constraint per table.

Have a look at the following example ....

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99e7f/1/0)

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
  col1 varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
  col2 varchar(50),
  col3 varchar(50),
  col4 varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT uc UNIQUE (col2,col3,col4)
 );
```

this should work:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('1','1','1','1');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('2','1','1','2');
```

this should fail:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('1','1','1','1');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('2','1','1','1');
```

Comment: Updated my question. Ur opinion now?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be able to add a multi-column unique constraint.
Something Like:

```
alter table TableA add CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(ColumnA2, ColumnA3, ColumnA4, ColumnA5)
```

Answer (score 0):

column  `ColumnCode`  is PK so its onl;y accept unique value for this column,

all the column `ColumnA1-5` are not unique column thats the reason it accepting all the duplicate value, if you want to avoid the duplicate entry in any of the column
   `create unique key`  on tht column .

```
alter table tableA add unique index(ColumnA2, ColumnA3, ColumnA4, ColumnA5);
```

this would solve ur problem

Comment: Updated my question. Ur opinion now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191524%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in your database.

The trigger is the code, which can run some code after the query or instead of query.
You can see some examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187834%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

But as mentioned in another answers it is simplier to use `UNIQUE` constraints.

Comment: Updated my question. Ur opinion now?

Answer (score 0):

alter table TableA add CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(ColumnA2, ColumnA3, ColumnA4, ColumnA5)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove all unique key

```
alter table TableA  drop unique key;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one checksum column of all column which need to be unique. And update in on all insert and update. Check if there ckecksum column exists before you update and insert any new row..  In ms sql i would do it like this

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
    (
      [ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [Index] [tinyint] NOT NULL ,
      [C0] [real] NOT NULL ,
      [C1] [real] NOT NULL ,
      [C2] [real] NOT NULL ,
      [C3] [real] NOT NULL ,

    )
ON  [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER test  ADD UQCHECKSUM AS BINARY_CHECKSUM(
[Index],
[C0] ,
[C1] ,
[C2] ,
[C3] ,
[) PERSISTED
Go  
ALTER TABLE test    ADD CONSTRAINT [UNK_UQCHECKSUM] UNIQUE (UQCHECKSUM)
GO
```

Pls check this for mysql 
http://www.bluegecko.net/mysql/using-checksums-to-ensure-table-consistency-in-mysql/

Comment: Updated my question. Ur opinion now?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
    (
      [ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [C1] [varchar] NOT NULL ,
      [C2] [varchar] NOT NULL ,
      [C3] [varchar] NOT NULL ,
      [C4] [varchar] NOT NULL ,
      [C5] [varchar] NOT NULL ,
      [ChecksumColumn] [varchar] NOT NULL //new column
    )
```

Create a insert and update  trigger on test table to find the checksum of columns (C1,C2,C3,c4,c5) and insert into ChecksumColumn
Use `CRC32(C1,C2,C3,c4,c5)` to get the check sum

Before insert and update check the below condition
Select top 1 from test where ChecksumColumn = `CRC32(C1,C2,C3,c4,c5)`

if exist -- Duplicate records
else  Go ahead and update the ChecksumColumn with `CRC32(C1,C2,C3,c4,c5)`